# Why JS Spread not cloning response headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

Using request-promise npm, made an GET call to an website url. Request contains

```
 const response = await requestPromise({
     url: url,
     headers: {
         'User-Agent': '',
     },
     encoding: null,
     resolveWithFullResponse: true
 })
```

Using spread operator, tried cloning the response

```
const respObj = {...response};
```

But respObj.headers is undefined but response.headers has value. Also when used

```
const respObj = {...response, headers: response.headers};
```

Both respObj and response has headers object.
May I know the reason behind this ?

Comment: First of all, you are using a library that has been deprecated for more than two years. You probably should switch to something else. Second, the spread syntax only only copies [*enumerable* properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). It *might* be (ie I don't know for sure) that `headers` is not enumerable ...

Comment: use some other library like `axios` or `node-fetch`